# Fixed points for increasing function

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points

Let $f(x):[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ a real-valued function that is strictly increasing in $x$. Further, $f(b)>b$. I would like to show that the function has at most two fixed points; is that true?
Graphing the function, I find three cases:

1. A single fixed point if $f(a)<a$
2. Either zero or two fixed points if $f(a)>a$.

Any ideas of how I can prove this formally? Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason that you believe that this is the case?

Comment: Definitely not. Take e.g. $f(x) = x$ for $x\in [a,b)$ and $f(b) = b+1$ as a counterexample. But even if you assumed that $f$ was continuous or even differentiable this surely wouldn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is clearly not true. As an example, take $f$ over $[0,2]$ to be given by
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x & x<1,\\
2x-1 & x\geq 1.
\end{cases}
$$
The function $f$ satisfies the necessary conditions but has infinitely many fixed points.

If you prefer a smooth example or an example with finitely many fixed points, you could also take a function of the form $f(x) = x + a\sin(bx)$ for suitable values of $a$ and $b$. For example, here is the graph of one such function over $[0,2\pi]$.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Building on the other answers. Here is a differentiable one:
$$ f(x) = x + \sin \left[\frac{k \pi(2x - a - b)}{2(b-a)} \right]. $$
Let $k$ vary as much as you want to get any number of zeros you'd like (ensure that $\sin(\dots)$ remains positive though!).

Comment: Ah looks like Ben updated his answer to include a similar example. Ha, my bad.

Comment: The more the merrier. It's important to note here that for some values of $k$, this function is no longer increasing over all $x$ in the domain.

Comment: Yes good point. Just noticed it myself, I will update.

Comment: @Gregory Is there any smooth function with infinity number of fix points ?

Answer (score 1):

As other already said the proposition is not true. Under which assumptions could this be true? Consider if $x,y$ are two fixed points, so $f(x)=x$, $f(y)=y$. Then this proposition is essentially equivalent to $f$ not intersecting the diagonal  in a third point.

This would for example be true if $f$ was a strictly convex or concave function, which is probably what you had in mind when graphing your functions.

In this case your cases are almost correct assuming $f$ is continuous:

If $f(a)<a$ and $f(b) > b$ then by continuity you get at least one intersection $x$ such that $f(x) = x$. Assume $f$ is strictly convex. Then no point in $[a,x]$ can be a fixed point. But if you get another fixed point $y > x$ then no point in $[a,y]$ can be a fixed point, so $x$ is the only one (essentially any fixed point must be the smallest fixed point). Strictly concave goes the same way, just the other direction.

If on the other hand $f(a) > a$ and $f$ is strictly concave then there cannot be such a point. If $f$ is strictly concave all three $0,1$ or $2$ solutions are possible. If $f(a) = a$ $f$ can have 1 or 2 fixed points.